# Laravel File Not Found At Path - Storage::move

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've run across an interesting predicament with the Laravel Storage::move function. In my controller I have the following lines of code:

```
$path = $files->storeAs('/public/temp/agentBilling', $name);
$file = Storage::url($path);
```

Now, with the script that follows right after this, it can recognize and locate $file using this combination: `public_path() . $file;`

Which looks like: `E:/Apache/htdocs/CASAT/public/storage/temp/agentBilling/htz...jpeg`

But, a little bit lower in my script here:

`Storage::move(public_path() . $file, '/public/temp/agentBilling'.$pro.'.jpeg');`

It says File not found at path:... even though that path (`E:/Apache/htdocs/CASAT/public/storage/temp/agentBilling/htz...jpeg`) is the same as above....

I've looked and there is a file at the path with the given name. I'm not sure what else to try. I'm just trying to rename the file at this point to see if it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Hi - It can be found here: https://jsonblob.com/cd65885a-d314-11e8-9c58-3b8902d9c852